# mPDF generate multiple PDF's in loop with Dynamic HTML template

Tags: php, mpdf, output-buffering

I am trying to generate multiple quotes using a dynamic html template that accepts a quote id. When looping through the id's the first PDF is generated and then fails with the following error ...

"PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on null in /home/eepherg/public_html/mobiquote1.2/followups.php on line 22"

It seems the include is the problem, if I remove it from the loop then multiple blank PDF's are created. How do i include the dynamic template with output buffering multiple times ... here is my code, any help would be most appreciated.

```
<?php

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/mpdf/mpdf.php");

require ("/home/eepherg/cnct_mobiquote.php");

try {
        $sql = "SELECT 
                    a.headersid, 
                    c.email,
                    a.ref,
                    a.description,
                    c.clientname,
                    d.doc_template
                 FROM `headers` a 
                 JOIN `users` b ON a.userid = b.userid
                 JOIN `clients` c ON a.clientid = c.clientid
                 JOIN companies d ON a.companyid = d.companyid
                 WHERE a.follow_up_1 = CURRENT_DATE AND a.status = 2 AND a.active = 1"; //only incomplete and emailed quotes
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {

                    $quoteid = $row[0];
                    $email = $row[1];
                    $quote_ref = $row[2];
                    $description = $row[3];
                    $client = $row[3];
                    $quote_template = $row[5];

                    //-- generate the .pdf 

                        //set the path for the temp pdf
                        $savedtemppdf = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/mobiquote1.2/temp_pdf/".$quote_ref.".pdf";

                        $mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',20,15,30,25,10,10);
                        $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
                        $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;  // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list

                        $mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch';
                        $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('');

                        ob_start( );
                        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/mobiquote1.2/templates/".$quote_template.".php?id=".$quoteid);
                        $output = ob_get_clean( );
                        ob_end_clean();

                        $mpdf->WriteHTML($output);
                        $mpdf->Output($savedtemppdf,'F');

                    //email the quote with attachment
            }
}

catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Error: ' . "<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
}

//close the connection
$stmt = null;
$conn = null; 

?>
```

Comment: You have some `sql` error - debug it first.

Comment: @freeek, thank you for your response. I have taken the SQL statement as per above and run it in MYSQL with no errors. The issue seems to be the multiple includes of the template file in the loop. I don't know how else to do it while maintaining the functionality of the dynamic template. Any ideas?